# looping com dplyr no R

Tags: r, loop, dplyr

Há dias procuro uma solução para uma questão. Pretendo criar uma estrutura de repetição que permita guardar uma tabela para cada classe de acordo com o código abaixo, filtrando e salvando automaticamente, sem que eu precise substituir as letras da "classe1" um por um.

```
library(dplyr)

id = c(1:20)
classe1 = as.factor(c("a","a","b","c","b","c","a","a","a","a","c","c","b","b","a","c","b","b","b", "c"))
classe2 = as.factor(c("alfa","alfa","gama","gama","gama","alfa","gama","alfa","gama","gama","gama","alfa","gama","gama","gama","alfa","alfa","alfa","alfa", "gama"))
tabela <- data.frame(id, classe1, classe2)

teste <- tabela %>%
  filter(classe1 == "a")%>%
  group_by(classe2) %>%
  summarise(n=length(id))
       
write.table(teste, "a.csv", row.names = F)
```

pretendia, com essa função, gerar e salvar no diretorio tres arquivos .csv, nomeados... O dplyr ta certo... fora da função ele funciona. Mas a função... embora retorne sem erro, nao gera nada. onde estou errando aqui

A função:

```
level<-c("a", "b", "c")
level<- as.factor(level)  

for(i in 1:length(level)){

  teste <- tabela %>%
    filter(classe1 == print(paste(level[i])))%>%
    group_by(classe2) %>%
    summarise(n=length(id))
      
  write.table(teste, paste0(raiz, level[i],'.csv'), row.names = F) 
}
```

Comment: Isto é completamente desnecessário: `print(paste(level[i]))`. Só `level[i]` faz exatamente o mesmo, tente.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui está uma função que divide a tabela por valores de `"classe1"` e escreve os ficheiros correspondentes. Testado com `raiz` tal como definida abaixo.

```
fun_dplyr <- function(x, col, raiz){
  x %>%
    group_split(!!sym(col)) %>% 
    purrr::map(~write.table(.x, paste0(raiz, first(.x[[col]]), ".csv"), row.names = FALSE))
}

raiz <- "~/tmp/"

fun_dplyr(tabela, col = "classe1", raiz)
```